# Android Emulator failed to get the latest version

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, gradle

*I know a lot of you will want to mark it as duplicate, but this is a specific question, please read full before any action*

I am using Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017 Community for my Windows 7 Laptop.

I got the HXAM installed and then i also wen to BIOS to fix the Visualization settings.

Now when i run any cross-platform app, using the emulator (Android 6.0 - API 23 | ARM), i get the below error:

```
    1>emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
    1>emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error
    1>emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '25.2.5-3567187')
    1>...
    1>...
    1>...
    1>...
    1>Emulator is not ready to be used.
    1>Deploy failed on RealDeal
```

Few things to note here:

- The project doesn't deploy.
- I have looked at such previous questions.
- I tried this both in Debug and Release modes.
- They suggest a line of code to be run on the command line - `emulator.exe -avd <avd_name> -no-audio -http-proxy <proxy_name>:<proxy_port>` However, i am not aware of where is this Console and that how do i find my proxy name for this thing to work (i dont ave rights to look at the proxy details as i am blocked from my company website to do so.)
- Other solution i see is that i should include some code in my Gradle. (I don't have that Gradle file in my project)
- I tried increasing the RAM and all those memories.
- Hyper-V is disabled.

Please help me find a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn´t use ARM, but Atom (x86).

TL;DR

When Visual Studio installs Android stuff, you got 4 emulators by default:

[image]

**VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone** is the one you want to use.

If it´s not there for any reason, you can create it yourself by going to **Tools > Android > Android Emulator Manager > Create** then set the details like the screenshoot above.

Make sure that CPU/ABI is set to Google APIs Intel Atom (x86), otherwise XHAM won´t work.

Before doing this, make sure hxam is installed (on the Android SDK Manager):

[image]

Last but not least, make sure the emulator is selected for the build:[image]

Comment: The HXAM sill says that it is "Not Compatible with windows". However, i followed your other instructions, and it works! I guess the AVD that i was using was not tailored properly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your internet connection. I had the same issue after installing my new firewall.